# What is the meaning of the phrase "striving for effect"?

Tags: idioms, phrase-usage, literary-english

This phrase seems to be well established in English. I just don't know exactly what it means, beyond the fact that it is used to define "affectation".

It may be something that people learn about in literary criticism or art history classes. To *strive for effect* is a defect in a work of art. There's an ambiguity here, because effects are wanted—so apparently it's the (strained-seeming) striving that's bad? If the phrase refers to "tryhard" behaviour, is there an elitism to it: a valorization of effortlessness?

Example:

> Jones wins us over early on, and we warm to her voice — thoughtful, earnest, with a lifelong editor's aversion to the slightest striving for effect.

https://www.nytimes.com/2007/11/04/style/tmagazine/04tbrubach.html

Example from ca. 1830:

> There is a great deal of what you, in critical phraseology, might term straining for point; striving for effect; endeavouring to excite a sensation

https://books.google.ie/books?id=HrZNAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22striving%20for%20effect%22%20cork%20dublin&pg=PA395#v=onepage&q=%22striving%20for%20effect%22%20cork%20dublin&f=false

There must be a point at which this idiom was consciously introduced.

Comment: Maybe you could provide an *in vivo* example?

Comment: Done. They're not hard to find. Explanations seem to be, though!

Comment: It probably goes back to the editors' desire not to be taken out of the narrative by ham-fisted prose that calls attention to itself. *Look at how clever I am!* it shrieks. That sort of thing. They feel it should read effortlessly. Updike's prose would be an example, I suppose. But if *you're* going for the scintillations Updike pulled off with ease, then you're trying too hard.

Comment: *Striving for effect* just means *trying too hard* or *straining*. Can you further articulate your concerns about the ambiguousness of that?

Comment: I have added the tag "idioms" because I think this phrase has a specific connotation beyond its literal meaning. It was introduced at a certain point (early 19th C?) and there are some implicit values associated with it—effortlessness and naturalness are good; effects are wanted, but not to be strained for. I guess I want to know what critical theory the idiom comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Strive* is a particularly apt verb for this expression, since the criticism is about revealing the (significant) effort behind the effect.

**strive**

> Make great efforts to achieve or obtain something. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/Make)

> To endeavour vigorously, use strenuous effort.
>
> **c1384**   *Bible* (Wycliffite, E.V.) (Douce 369(2)) (1850) 2 Cor.
> v. 9   And therfore we stryuen [L. *contendimus*] whether absent,
> whether present, for to plese him. (OED)

---

The earliest example of **strive for effect** I've found in Google books is:

> Accustom yourself to consider your own interests as identified with
> those of your master; and look upon every customer who comes into your
> master's shop as being friendly to those interests, and intending to
> confer upon him a personal favour.  You will then feel yourself bound
> to show good will and gratitude, both on your master's account an on
> your own. Let this good will and gratitude be expressed in the way
> most natural to yourself at the time, without any effort or **striving
> for effect**, and you may then be pretty certain of deserving and
> enjoying a reputation for well-bred affability. [The Religious Tract
> Society; *The Apprentice: Or, Affectionate Hints to a Young Friend
> Entering Upon the Business of Life*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Apprentice/p4RQAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=striving%20for%20effect&pg=PA106&printsec=frontcover) (1799)

Examples that provide some motivation for using the expression may give you a better idea of what may constitute *striving for effect*:

> A style based on copying the *Chunhua ge tie*, for example, would be
> seen as premeditated and **striving for effect**, with all the
> negative associations such as cleverness, mannerism, and disguising
> the self behind stylistic quotation. [Amy McNair; *The Upright
> Brush*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Upright_Brush/o6ABEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22striving%20for%20effect%22%20is%20seen%20in&pg=PA68&printsec=frontcover) (1998)

> For this nonchalance, Castiglione coins the Italian term [*sprezzatura*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprezzatura)
> (from *sprezzo* 'disdain, scorn'), which signifies an apparent disdain
> for 'sweat', for effort. Defined negatively, it is the avoidance of a
> conscious **striving for effect**, of 'affectation' (*affettazione*).
> The ideal courtier cultivates the favour of the powerful by appearing
> to be indifferent as to its attainment. [B. Kane and V. McGown-Doyle;
> *Elizabeth I and Ireland*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Elizabeth_I_and_Ireland/Wby0BAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22striving%20for%20effect%22%20defined&pg=PA82&printsec=frontcover) (2014)

> "... the tawdry marks of the Mannerist are not merely stiffness and
> monotony, disparity and inconsistency, but distortion and
> overrichness, exaggeration and a frantic **striving for effect**."
> [Max Jakob Friedländer in  A. Radermecker; *Anonymous Art at
> Auction*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Anonymous_Art_at_Auction/JkwwEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22striving%20for%20effect%22%20defined&pg=PA219&printsec=frontcover) (2021)

> As evidence, Freytag submits the following list of Wagnerian traits:
> "**Striving for effect** by pretentiously and coldly calculating means
> (but unregulated by true artistic feeling);... [Nicholas Vazsonyi,
> *Wagner's Meistersinger*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Wagner_s_Meistersinger/pyfBBS-L_4oC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22striving%20for%20effect%22%20defined&pg=PA186&printsec=frontcover) (2003)

> The design, which dates from 1893, was some three years in
> construction; and although both the interior and the exterior display
> the ostentatious **striving for effect** typical of that time, ... [R.
> Stephen Sennott; *Encyclopedia of Twentieth Century Architecture*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Encyclopedia_of_Twentieth_Century_Archit/O9jeQtQ5CKgC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22striving%20for%20effect%22%20defined&pg=PA1201&printsec=frontcover)
> (2004)

> In spite of this, it is an undisputed fact that an audience recognizes
> nothing so quickly as false and deceptive character portraiture. This
> fact should warn the author against **striving for effect** at the
> expense of true characterization. [*The Editor: The Journal of
> Information for Literary Workers*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Editor/rF04AQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22striving%20for%20effect%22%20defined&pg=PA340&printsec=frontcover) (1917)

> There is always to be found a quiet, forceful intelligence in all of
> their work; no conscious **striving for effect**; no attempt at
> ostentatious or showy forms, but invariable dignity and excellence of
> composition and effect, subtilty. [*The New York Architect, vol. 3,
> n.2*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_New_York_Architect/m8pJAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22striving%20for%20effect%22%20is%20seen%20in&pg=PP120&printsec=frontcover) (1909)

---

Comment: So it's clearly a thing, an idiom in criticism. Do you think it's a translation of a work from another language (e.g. Effekthascherei in German)? I don't feel like I know what it means until I know the context in which the idiom gained currency. Hope that is reasonable!

Comment: If it was originally a translation, it has been a full-fledged expression for some time as the dates show. I would note the adjectives used in the examples. In a nutshell it can be effect for effect's sake, a lack of subtlety, overdone, showing effort, sort seeing how the trick is done, ostentatious, self-conscious, affected, insincere, etc..

Comment: I think it might be properly considered a term from rhetoric, or a characteristic of classical rhetoric: "THUCYDIDES left no such impress upon subsequent Greek historians as might have been expected. He remained a great name; but few read and fewer imitated him. His severe yet lofty style and his passion for the truth were  foreign to the taste of the age that followed. For although history did not revert to poetry, it passed into the field of rhetoric, where the ideal was a striving for effect rather than for fact."  (James T. Shotwell, The Story of Ancient History)

Comment: @TheoH We see that the expression is especially handy for use in criticism in the arts, including literature and rhetoric. The 1799 example could be referring especially to speech (sales talk/conversations with customers).

Answer (score 0):

If the goal of art is to communicate, striving for effect can diminish that. Our attention is on the artistry and not the art - on the effort that is being expended, and not on the message. Perhaps the message isn't all that clear, and the artist is trying too hard to compensate. Natural effortlessness, where the art can speak for itself, would be better.

Answer (score 0):

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strive)
>
> Strive:
>
> to try very hard to do something or to make something happen, especially for a long time or against difficulties

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/effect?q=Effect)
>
> Effect:
>
> the result of a particular influence

To strive for an effect is thus to work hard or long at producing a result.

To the person who perceives the effect it may be obvious that too much effort or time has been spent on the effect, at the expense of wider values or aspects such as the context or meaning. Or that too much time and effort has been spent on achieving a result because the creator is consciously trying to satisfy a fashion or fad for it rather than using it in wide artistic context.

Examples? Three will serve to illustrate how *some* viewers perceive some *striving* (these views are not necessarily mine):

The pop concert with over-use of dry ice where the promoters have put too much effort into the ambiance in order to hide a second-rate singer.
The prime minister who embellishes his speeches with excessive witty word-smithing at the expense of dealing seriously with the issues he speaks of.
The interior designer who labours hard to create transient novelty as a mark of their unique creativity, at the expense of the comfort of the residents. All these are striving for effect.

Compare them with the (as seen by *some* people) effortless effects of a natural singer, a dedicated politician, an empathetic designer.